# How to blend two CALayers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, calayer

Does anyone know how I can blend two CALayers? I have one layer that is an image, and I want to blend that with a UITableViewCell's contentView layer. How would I go about this?

So my designers gave me an overlay image, that is a gradient. Here is what it looks like:
[image]

I need to blend this image with the layer of a view. Right now, I am just creating a layer who's contents are this image, and adding it as a sublayer of the view's layer, and I am getting this: 
[image]

As you can see, the color of the image is white, so it is just being added on top of the view's layer. What I want is to blend this layer with the view's layer, so the gradient is the same color as the layer's background color. I am not sure about how I can do this, because I haven't used Core Animation very much.

Comment: `Blend` is too broad and does not have enough detail. Can you provide images of what outcome you are having now and an image showing the expect outcome? Otherwise my only advice is change the `alpha` property.

Comment: Does this help clear things up?

Comment: Yes.  I've upvoted the question as I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: you certainly do *not* want to use an image for your gradient. there is a `CAGradientLayer`.